# Django URL Config For Dev and Prod

Tags: python, django

My django app's urls are setup as follows for my development machine:

urls.py:

urlpatterns = [

```
url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
url(r'^signin$', signin, name='signin'),
url(r'^signout$', signout, name='signout'),
url(r'^advisor/', include('apps.advisor.urls', namespace='advisor')),
```

]

This setup works fine while developing the app using Django's builtin server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000).  I have to deploy the app to a machine and the Django app is exposed by the following url:

http://ip address/appname/

I'd like to have my urls.py file configured so the regular expression in the url tests to see if the url request starts with "appname" or "" (empty string).  This method would mean I don't have to create to urls.py files (dev and prod versions).  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to do this at all. When your app is deployed via WSGI, the server should pass on the SCRIPT_NAME parameter which identifies the path it is mounted at. As long as you have consistently used `{% url %}` and `reverse()` throughout your app rather than hard-coding links, everything will just work.

Comment: I do use named urls and reverse (reverse_lazy)  However, when the app is deployed the beginning of the url goes from http://127.0.0.0.1:8000 to http://123.245.1/app  In this case the start of the urls no longer match.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your deployment. Please give the details of how you are deploying, and show your server configuration files (in the question).

Comment: Slow response on my part.  My django app is configured correctly.  I have not worked much with the http server config side before.  That has usually been handled by our sysadmins.  What I have learned is that I have to figure out the nginx rewrite setup so that http://ip_address/folder gets passed to http://ip_address:9000 and the appropriate url gets passed back to the client.

Comment: I think I have figured out the real question.  Our sysadmins have a url http://company.com/app, public facing. They use apache http server.   The sysadmin have http://company.com/app pointing to http://internal_ip_address:8080.  I have nginx sitting on internal_ip:address listening on 8080.  I am trying to get nginx to take requests coming into http://internal_ip_address, route the requests to http://localhost:9000 which is a django app.  Once django is done with the request the resulting page renders with appropriate public facing url (e.g. http://company.com/app . . .)  Thanks for any help!